# Vim command-line just say 'saved' upon save

Tags: command-line, statusline

In Vim, at the the bottom.
There is statusline.

And below it there is, I think, the command line.

When I press save, this command line, displays something like:

```
"index" 160 lines, 2097 characters written
```

But I don't want it to display this.

I would only like it to display something like:

```
Saved.
```

How do I do that?

Comment: So far, relying on the `[+]` marker in the statusline to show unsaved modifications has served me well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the `BufWriteCmd` to override the `write` operation:

```
augroup OverrideWrite
autocmd!
autocmd! BufWriteCmd * silent w | echo 'Saved'
augroup END
```

Comment: I would much prefer to see `w` written out as `write`, especially in example code.

Comment: Also, you're missing handling all the stuff in `:help Cmd-event`. Probably just using `BufWritePost` to echo a message suffices.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble, I have tried `BufWritePost` but I ended to have both messages instead of only the desired `Saved`.

Comment: I still think you're missing a lot of details for BufWriteCmd to work correctly, and this probably breaks plugins that use it.

Comment: Now if I update the vimrc with ':source $MYVIMRC'. Then after that, 'saved' is typed twice. And as I do it more often, the saved message gets more numerous.

Comment: I have updated the solution to avoid that problem :-)